# QT Prevent User From Entering Illegal Data, But with QCompletor

Tags: c++, qt

When there is a large amount of data in a `QComboBox` it seems reasonable to attach a `QCompleter` by enabling combo boxes `editable` property.

Even though completer feature is needed, it should not allow any data that is not already in the combo box to be added by the user (by typing and hitting the enter key)

Text are of variable length. So it should allow the user to complete it. So using a `QValidator` and checking it in the list of strings did not work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and if size of data doesn't decrease performance, than you can use this simplest solution:

When user want enter data, check is this data exist in your combo.

For example:

```
void MainWindow::on_userWantsEnterDataButton_clicked()
{
    QString current = ui->comboBox->currentText();
    QStringList items;
    for(int i = 0; i < ui->comboBox->count(); ++i)
    {
        items << ui->comboBox->itemText(i);
    }
    if(items.contains(current))
    {
        qDebug() << "good";
        //nextAction();
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "very bad";
}
```

Edit

Yes, you are right, you should listen to enter keys. There are a few ways to do this. First, you can subclass QComboBox, but there is way without subclassing, you should install eventFilter.

I show you my code, whick works as you want. In my case, I wrote code in the MainWindow class

In the mainwindow.h

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
```

In the mainwindow.cpp

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor

//...

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(obj == ui->comboBox)
    {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if(Qt::Key_Return == keyEvent->key() || Qt::Key_Enter == keyEvent->key() )
        {
            qDebug() << "inside";

            QString current = ui->comboBox->currentText();
            QStringList items;
            for(int i = 0; i < ui->comboBox->count(); ++i)
            {
                items << ui->comboBox->itemText(i);
            }
            if(items.contains(current))
            {
                qDebug() << "good";//nextAction();
                return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);

            }
            else
            {
                //if user want enter illegal data, we set first item and ignore user's changes, you can do here what you want
                if(ui->comboBox->count() != 0)
                    ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(0);
                qDebug() << "very bad";
                return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);

            }

        }
    }
    }
    else
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);

}
```

When I enter data which exist in combo - it good, but if I want add something illegal, app ignore me. Also we listen to 2 enters, main and enter on the num pad.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But when user enters an incorrect data and hits the enter key, it is added to the combo box as well. So I guess I have to listen to the combo boxes enter key signal and remove the newly added value as well.

Comment: Thank you. Will follow your suggestion.